# Power BI - Numeric values displaying on a grid map image based on slicer selection

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Hi all Power BI experts,

I have a PBI report looks like below. The map on the left is an image. The data on the right comes from DirectQuery.

[image]

The users request to have the T Values to be displayed on the map next to the grid IDs dynamically based on the menu option they click on.

Is there anyway to achieve this requirement? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It can be used with "Synoptic panel" downloaded from PBI market place. The creator is okviz. Here is the URL for the visual: https://okviz.com/synoptic-panel/

Answer (score 1):

You could put a card in each rectangle with a different measure for each `Grid ID`.

Not an elegant solution, but I don't know that there is a good way to do this if you just have a flat image file with no programmatically defined way to map `Grid ID` values to map sections.